# Add html to menu title in Drupal

Tags: menu, drupal-7

I must have missed something. I can't figure out how to add some HTML into the title of the menu.

According to the [menu api](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7.x), I can't add `options` because I am using MENU_LOCAL_TASK, but then how? There is no say.

For example: if I try to make the title bold:

```
$items['whatever/tab2'] = array(
  'title' => '<b>Tab 2</b>',
  'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
);
```

This is not working.

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'title callback' => 'example_title_callback',

Function to generate the title; defaults to t(). If you require only the raw string to be output, set this to FALSE.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Menu HTML](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_html) module.